# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value when running T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sql-server-2019, datetime, date-format

Please note I am not a coder by any means, I am simply trying to assist with a migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2008 to SQL Server 2022 and 2019.

When I execute the following T-SQL query:

```
select convert(datetime,'08/15/2022',103)
```

I get an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

When I change it to:

```
select convert(datetime,'08/15/2022',101)
```

...it works.

I know UK English does not use mm/dd/yyyy, it was a test I was doing to see which default language SQL Server was using, so I could identify an issue in a website. I am looking therefore to set the default language in SQL to UK English instead of US English.

I did use backup/restore migration. It seems SQL Server 2019 interprets SQL queries slightly differently from SQL Server 2008. I have no access to the coded webpages, so I cannot make any changes to the ASP coding.

Is there *any* way I can run some T-SQL query to change the way SQL Server 2019 sees the date and force it to use UK English?

The server region settings are set correctly, to English South Africa (the same as UK English), so I am not sure where else I can make any changes so that we get the correct date and time format.

If I change the default language of the user in question, will this achieve my goal and do I need to restart SQL server in order to implement the change? The user I am referring to is the user set in SQL to connect to the database to run queries, set in the ODBC Driver settings.

This is in relation to a website we are running, which I cannot change coding for as I know nothing about ASP.

This is the code causing the issue:

```vb
sSQL = "UPDATE VR_UPLOAD SET clnt_status = 'O', clnt_date_send = '" & 
Left(strDate, 2) & "-" & Mid(strDate, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(strDate, 4) & " " & 
Left(strTime, 2) & ":" & Mid(strTime, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(strTime, 2) & ".000', 
CLNT_OUTFILE = '" & strFileName & 
"' where clnt_validated = '' and clnt_status = 'i'"
oConn.Execute(sSQL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Martin Smith in his deleted answer:

> It is the default language of the login that determines the default way that string dates are interpreted but this is not relevant to your question as you are specifying the style parameter explicitly anyway.

### Possible Solutions

Nonetheless, I would like to point out a couple of possible solutions.

> **WARNING**
> Please read before applying any of the given solution.
> Both solution could cause issues in production.
> Backup your database / data beforehand.

#### 1. Change SQL Server Instance Language

Set the default language of the SQL Server instance via:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'default language', N'23'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

23 is the langid for British English as can be retrieve in the `sys.syslanguages` table:

> ```
> +--------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------+
> | langid | dateformat | datefirst | upgrade |  name   |      alias      |                                        months                                         |                   shortmonths                   |                           days                           | lcid | msglangid |
> +--------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------+
> |     23 | dmy        |         1 |       0 | British | British English | January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December | Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec | Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday | 2057 |      1033 |
> +--------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------+
> ```

> ***NOTE / CAUTION!***
> However, I would **not recommend** this as your SQL Server instance "has been"/"is" running with a predefined language. You might break things.
> **Please test before implementing!**

You can verify the server's current running settings with this script:

```
SELECT sc.value_in_use, sl.langid, sl.name, sl.alias,sl.[dateformat] FROM sys.configurations AS sc 
    JOIN sys.syslanguages AS sl
        ON sl.langid = sc.value_in_use 
WHERE sc.name = 'default language';
```

On my SQL Server instance this yields:

> ```
> +--------------+--------+------------+---------+------------+
> | value_in_use | langid |    name    |  alias  | dateformat |
> +--------------+--------+------------+---------+------------+
> |            0 |      0 | us_english | English | mdy        |
> +--------------+--------+------------+---------+------------+
> ```

#### 2. Change Client Connection Settings

Change the language setting in the script you are currently running with the following SET command:

```
set language = uk_english
go
<your statements>
go
```

> **NOTE / CAUTION**
> Please test before using in production.

#### 3. Set Dateformat

Change the dateformat before you run your script:

```
set dateformat MDY
go
<your statements>
go
```

#### 4. Change the Default Language of the SQL Server Login

In case you want to change the default language of the SQL Server login execute a similar script to:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [mojo] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

#### Reference Reading

- [sys.syslanguages (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [SET LANGUAGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Configure the default language Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-default-language-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Server Configuration Options (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-configuration-options-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [SET DATEFORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [International Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-international-settings-in-windows?view=windows-11) (Windows 11)

Comment: @JohnK.N. My apologies, I should have mentioned that this issue is resolved, I had to manually set Server 2022 regional settings to the same as SQL server date and time settings, which is yyyy/mm/dd-hh:mm:ss am/pm

Comment: Ok. I'll edit something and you can take the accepted answer away again and add your solution as an answer.